# Two way repeated measures with baseline and multiple time-points

Tags: r, time-series, anova, repeated-measures, ancova

We have a repeated measures experiment. Each person had their temperature measured once before, and every minute (for 15 minutes) after two different interventions.

As each of the two different interventions were performed on different days, we want to control for baseline (i.e. pre) temperature.

We are looking at whether there is any difference between the two interventions in temperature, and whether there are changes in recovery in temperature during the first 16 minutes post intervention.

My thinking is a two-way repeated measures ANOVA (i.e. time * intervention) of the measurements taken over the 15 minutes. We want to be able to include the baseline measure as a covariate as well.

Two questions:

1. Does the two-way RM ANOVA seem to be the best approach?
2. How would it be possible to include the covariate into the model in R?

Thank you